# Researching Kisting immigration to Namibia?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, immigration

I am looking for the information of Rudolf Kisting who ended up in Namibia possibly between 1850 and 1900.  He married a namibian women with the surname Wimmerth and died in around 1950 in Namibia.  He had 12 brothers. It said that he was born or descending from Berlin, Germany.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE! "It is said" -- who said? This question could be improved by telling us what sources you've already looked at. Take a look at the help center, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for our site guidelines.

Comment: Do you know why Rudolf travelled to Namibia? It looks like numerous Germans went there as part of the [Rhenish Mission](http://www.safrika.org/rhenish_en.html), but there were also commercial and colonisation efforts in that timeframe. If you have an idea of why he was there, you might be able to narrow your focus onto the more relevant records.

Answer (score 1):

It would appears that Rudolf Kisting,or a desentant of his was in Namibia rather later than you had thought.

'Rudolf Kisting, a member of the SYL in Namibia in the 1970s, enjoyed a. meal with Nujoma in Harare in ...'

You may also wish to contact Elena Torreguitar, who has interviewed Rudolf Kisting, in the course of her research for the following publication and who may be able to put you in contact with him.

National Liberation Movements in Office: Forging Democracy with African Adjectives in Namibia (Europaeische Hochschulschriften / European University Studies / Publications Universitaires Europeennes) New edition by Elena Torreguitar (ISBN: 9783631579954)

Answer (score 0):

To begin researching this I think you should pursue avenues for trying to determine which pieces of the information that you have presented can be relied upon the most in order to verify their sources and content.

For example, I notice that your username bears the same surname of Kisting so if you are able to trace your ancestry to Rudolf then any records tying you and your nearer ancestors may be useful in trying to tie down the period during which Rudolf lived in Namibia.

From that a death record or immigration record may provide a town/region name for his birth in Germany.

You also mention that he had 12 brothers, so if you have names for any of them, and where they lived, then that too may help find additional sources for information about Rudolf's birth family.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say what the names of Rudolf Kisting's 12 brothers were but the sons of his son, Eduard Kisting who got married to a namibian women from the southern part of Namibia also had 12 sons who are Hans, Eduard, Rudolf, Adolf, Karl, Eduard, Dawid, Willem, Paul, Johannes, Michael, Daniel.  These names are known as ancestral names.

I am married Paul the grandson of Rudolf Kisting and son to Eduard/ Edward Kisting. Edward is said to come over to Namibia with his parents from Germany as a very young child.

It would be good to get in contact with Elena Torrequitar to find out more about Rudolf Kisting from SYL.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your answer could be improved by adding the sources for the information you have shared here.  How do you know the names of the 12 sons  of Eduard Kisting? Have they been passed down in your family stories or do you have a reference to a published work? "It is said" that Edward came to Nambia with his parents from Germany -- but who says so?  As genealogists we need to know how the information is transmitted in order to evaluate the quality of the information.  You can use the edit link under your answer at any time to add more information.